# Pulling User Information from Parse Database

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using Parse as my backend for my app.  Once the user logs into their account I am trying to get the next view to say "Welcome, (First Name)" at the top.  However, I cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish this even using Parse's online documents.  Their site directed me here for further assistance.  I have tried using their query feature, but could not figure it out.  In other words, I am trying to pull the current logged in user's first name, from the database and display it once logged in.

Current code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"firstName" equalTo:currentUser]; // find user's first name
NSArray *firstName = [query findObjects];
```

Previous code:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser) {
    // do stuff with the user
    Welcome.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome,", currentUser];
```

Comment: Have you tried using this instead: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome, %@", currentUser];`? When using a format string, as in stringWithFormat, you need to use %@ as the identifier for your string you provide, i.e. `currentUser`.

Comment: I just tried, but it now shows something like <PFUser: 0x458679c...>.

Answer (score 0):

Your overcomplicating things.

You don't have to execute a query every time the view loads, instead you should put this in a plist or NSUserDefaults as not to use an API request simply to display the current users name.

However, you can do the following to the current users username :

```
if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    Welcome.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome, %@", [PFUser currentUser].username];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check if you actually sign-up and/or logged into Parse with this kind of function:

```
[PFUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
}];

[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:@"My username" password:@"My password" block:^(PFUser *validUser, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Check this link: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-signup/iOS

After you did this, whenever you you want to retrieve your user information,

`[PFUser currentUser]` is the right way to call some information:

Say for example you want to retrieve the objectId you can get it like this:

```
NSString *str = [PFUser currentUser].objectId;
```

Or say you want to set a custom value like this:

```
NSString *str = @"My custom object";
[PFUser setObject:str forKey:@"MyCustomObject"];
[PFUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Than you retrieve it like this:

```
NSString *str = [PFUser objectForKey:@"MyCustomObject"];
```

You should really check the documentation and example by Parse that are really well explained ! ;)

(Here are some tutorials/Examples by Parse: https://parse.com/tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

How is the transition from your login to your main view set up? Are they both two different controllers?

If so, you should look into NSNotificationCenter...

In your MainViewController, implement

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(loadObjects)
                                             name:@"loginFinished"
                                           object:nil];
```

And `loadObjects` will be

```
- (void)loadObjects
{
  Welcome.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@", [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:"userNameField"]];
}
```

*** You need to parse the PFUser object to access its fields. Its just a dictionary so supply it a key 'username' or whatever, and you receive a value 'myusername'. ***

Then in your `LoginViewController`, within your `[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:password:block`

Implement this

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:@"My username" password:@"My password" block:^(PFUser *validUser, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loginFinished" object:nil];

  }
}];
```

But this is basically how you should setup your login->main flow. Learn NSNotifications, Delegation, and maybe KVO... Learning these will make you a understand how data can be passed around in the iOS/Mac environment.

Heres an analogy for all of them:

`NSNotification`: A teacher(NSNotification poster) announces a test to all his students(NSNotification observer), or at least the one's who are currently in class, students missing class aren't observing.

`Delegate`: A student finishes a test and informs the professor(delegate).

`KVO`: A student(KVO poster) completes a question and raises their hand where the teacher or even other students could be KVOs (key-value observers) and act on their action.